# Change checkbox value with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="N" checked>
```

How can I change value with jquery?

I try to use `name` to my input like `<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="N" checked>` then in js I try to get it as: 
`$('input[type=checkbox][name=chk]').val == "Y";` 
but it isn´t work

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: If you have already tried something, post it on your question, please.

Comment: Sorry: I try to use name to my input like `<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="N" checked>` then in js I try to get it as: `$('input[type=checkbox][name=chk]').val == "Y";` bu it isn´t work @NewToJS

Comment: You're writting in jQuery, not JS.

Comment: So you're using jQuery..... did you include the jQuery library?

Comment: Editted sorry for inconvenients @NewToJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [jQuery documentation for `.val( value )`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value)

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=chk]').val("Y");
```

Here's a quick example:

```js
// Cache your Element
var $chk = $('input[type=checkbox][name=chk]');

// Setter: .val( value )
$chk.val("Y");

// Getter: .val(  )
var currentValue = $chk.val();

// Test:
console.log( currentValue );     // "Y"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="N" name="chk" checked>
```